# Is there a way to run light node(spv node) with Nodeos?

Tags: nodeos

I'm trying Nodeos, but full-syncing takes too much time. Is there a way to light-sync Nodeos? Such as "syncmode=light" of Geth? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can run `nodeos` with `--validation-mode=light`. `nodeos --help` should provide information about the flags:

In [`plugins/chain_plugin/chain_plugin.cpp`](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/plugins/chain_plugin/chain_plugin.cpp#L243-L246):

> Chain validation mode ("full" or "light")
>
> - In "full" mode all incoming blocks will be fully validated
> - In "light" mode all incoming blocks headers will be fully validated; transactions in those validated blocks will be trusted